# java, line break makes a space

Tags: java, space

I'm working on a battleship game, and one of the requirements for testing is for it not to create spaces at the end of the line, honestly if it didn't have to pass the auto grader i really wouldn't care but heres the code

```
public void printStatus(){
    String letter = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
    System.out.print("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10");
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length;i++){
        System.out.print("\n" + letter.charAt(i));
        for(int a = 0; a < table[i].length;a++){
            if(table[i][a].getStatus() == 0){
                System.out.print(" -");
            }else if(table[i][a].getStatus() == 1){
                System.out.print(" X");
            }else if(table[i][a].getStatus() == 2){
                System.out.print(" O");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and heres a picture of what the autograder was crying about.
[autograder picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX5YW.png)
otherwise the code works perfectly fine but the spaces at the end of the lines are apparently the devil

Comment: Will ```System.out.println()``` make a difference?

Comment: I think the expected output finish with a space and not yours, not the other way arround.

Comment: That looks like the `\n` is being considered by the autograder as a normal char.

Comment: Is the difference that you have too many spaces, of that you are missing spaces?

Comment: To elaborate on Mark's comment, there's no newline at the end of the grid. Add a `System.out.println()`, or `System.out.print('\n') after the `for` loop. That autograder is buggy though. It needs its own autograder.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the expected output finish with a space and not yours, not the other way arround

I think [Lynch is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896613/java-line-break-makes-a-space/54896673#comment96562077_54896613).

What if you put `+ ' '` after `letter.charAt(i)` and replace `" O"` with `"O "` (same for `X` and `-`)?

Comment: your right it was the autograder wanting spaces after graph, i feel stupid. thank you i've been working on it for and hour and a half lol.

Comment: @JeffreyBaker Glad it helped.